FileTransForm@2 is throwing 'Cannot perform XML transformations on a non-Windows platform' for a json transformation
Since I'm getting The FileTransform@1 task is deprecated, please use a newer version of the FileTransform task warning for my pipelines I updated FileTransform@1 to FileTransform@2 See the code below.
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: 'Update the parameters in azuredeploy.web.parameters.json'
  inputs:
    folderPath: '**/'
    targetFiles: '**/azuredeploy.web.parameters.json'
    fileType: json

But that failed with error Cannot perform XML transformations on a non-Windows platform when it's an Json transformation.

Found out by trial and error that if you only want JSON variable substitution, you need to explicitly specify the "xmlTransformationRules", but leave it blank in order to disable XML transformations:
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: 'Update appSettings.json'
  inputs:
    folderPath: '**/'
    xmlTransformationRules: 
    jsonTargetFiles: 'appSettings.json'


Amazing this worked. thanks so much David! I don't know how much time I've wasted on trying to get this task to work on Linux agents. I think it's poorly documented.

At present, the FileTransform task supports file transformations only for XML files, and not for JSON files. See the documentation "FileTransform@2 - File transform v2 task".

For JSON files, you can use the FileTransform task to perform only variable substitution.


The FileTransform@2 task has different input options than FileTransform@1 task. The input options "targetFiles" and "fileType" are not available for FileTransform@2.
There are two new options (jsonTargetFiles and xmlTargetFiles) applied to FileTransform@2.
For your case, if you wants to use the FileTransform@2 task to perform variable substitution for JSON files, you can configure the task like as below.
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: '**/'
    jsonTargetFiles: '**/azuredeploy.web.parameters.json'



Hello @Bright Ran-MSFT, I'm migrating from v1 to v2 as well to replace variables in json file and getting this "##[error]Unable to apply transformation for the given package - Changes are already present in the package." even though it replaced with new values in the json. Is this expected since it currently doesn't support Json?

Replacing variables (variable substitution) is supported for JSON files on both task versions (v1 and v2). As stated above, after changing from v1 to v2 task, you need to adjust the input options that are available for v2 task. Since v2 task does not have the total same input options as v1 task. @Ia1

yes, the above error i mentioned is after adjusting to the new input options from v2 task.

I saw in documentation that in version @2 the xmlTransformationRules has a default value, even if I don't use it. So I gave it empty string ''. I think it tries behind the scene to do some xml File Transformations, and sometimes you only need Variables Substitution.
folderPath field I would say its where the azuredeploy.web.parameters.json resides.
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: Transform appsettings file
  inputs:
    folderPath: './src/MyProject/folder'
    xmlTransformationRules: ''
    jsonTargetFiles: '**/azuredeploy.web.parameters.json'


Hit same issue 1 week ago, thought I would update with my findings.
Found that MS had released an update to the package https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/bcbc0c9f3367ce02cbb916695b0aae75cf41d4f2
This now expects a new parameter enableXmlTransform, setting this to false works.
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: "Transform Json"
  inputs:
      folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/'
      enableXmlTransform: false
      jsonTargetFiles: '**/angular.json'

